# Passing Data activity to TabView in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

**I want to pass data from main activity to one tab of TabView.Here is my code and it isn't working,what to do now**

There is my codes 
MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    EditText text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.getInfoButton);
        text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gitHubUserName);
        Logger.addLogAdapter(new AndroidLogAdapter());



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final String user = text.getText().toString();
                Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Tab.class);
                in.putExtra("SS",user);
                Logger.d(user);

                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("NAME",user);
                ProfileActivity pro = new ProfileActivity();
                pro.setArguments(bundle);

                startActivity(in);
            }
        });





    }
}
```

my Adapter for tabViews :

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                ProfileActivity profileActivity=new ProfileActivity();
                return profileActivity;
            case 1:
                FollowersActivity followersActivity=new FollowersActivity();
                return followersActivity;
                case 2:
                PublicRepos publicRepos=new PublicRepos();
                return publicRepos;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Profile Info";
            case 1:
                return "Followers";
            case 2:
                return "Public Repos";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this is ProfileActivity where I want to pass the data which I got from EditText in Main Activity :

```
public class ProfileActivity extends Fragment {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView name;
    TextView bio;


    String text;

    public void dataPass(String txt){
        text = txt;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, container, false);
        name = rootView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        bio = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bio);
        Logger.addLogAdapter(new AndroidLogAdapter());


        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String nameString = bundle.getString("NAME");
        Logger.d(nameString);
        name.setText(nameString);


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

when I run the app, app stopped working and in logcat this error :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.salman.getgithubofgeek.Activity.Activity.Activites.ProfileActivity.onCreateView(ProfileActivity.java:43)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `setArguments` like that.

Do this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        final String user = text.getText().toString();
        Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Tab.class);
        in.putExtra("SS",user);
        in.putExtra("NAME",user);
        Logger.d(user);

        startActivity(in);
    }
});
```

then in `Tab` activity, pass the extra to the adapter wherever you call it like so:

```
PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(fm, user);
```

and make the following changes to the adapter class:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    String nameString;
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String nameString) {
        super(fm);
        this.nameString = nameString;
    }
    @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            ProfileActivity profileActivity=new ProfileActivity();
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("NAME",nameString);
            profileActivity.setArguments(bundle);
            return profileActivity;
        case 1:
            FollowersActivity followersActivity=new FollowersActivity();
            return followersActivity;
        case 2:
            PublicRepos publicRepos=new PublicRepos();
            return publicRepos;

        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Profile Info";
        case 1:
            return "Followers";
        case 2:
            return "Public Repos";
    }
    return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: given brother :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to add the `bundle` in fragment that is in `

> TabActivity

`and in`Pager` you are again declaring ProfileActivity  fragment that is with out

> setArguments()

.
All you need to do is send the `bundle` to `activity` first and then before using `ProfileActivity` fragment in `Pager` set the `bundle` to the `ProfileActivity` fragment.

Comment: I didn't get it...I request it to explain it clearly :D

Comment: sorry its actually putExtra("Name",user);

Comment: and for getting value from intent you can use getIntent().getStringExtra("Name")

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button;
EditText text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.getInfoButton);
    text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gitHubUserName);
    Logger.addLogAdapter(new AndroidLogAdapter());



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final String user = text.getText().toString();
            Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Tab.class);
            in.putExtra("SS",user);
            Logger.d(user);
           //modification goes here
            intent.putString("NAME",user);

            startActivity(in);
        }
    });





}
}
```

and

```
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            ProfileActivity profileActivity=new ProfileActivity();
           //modifications goes here
           Bundle b = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("NAME",user);
            profileActivity.setArguments(b);
            return profileActivity;
        case 1:
            FollowersActivity followersActivity=new FollowersActivity();
            return followersActivity;
            case 2:
            PublicRepos publicRepos=new PublicRepos();
            return publicRepos;

        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Profile Info";
        case 1:
            return "Followers";
        case 2:
            return "Public Repos";
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: there is no method called intent.putString();